# nestjs swagger default apiproperty to current date

Tags: swagger, nestjs

This is my code:

```
  @IsDate()
  @ApiProperty({
    type: Number,
  })
  updateTime: Date;
```

How can I add default value to current date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/types-and-parameters), you can change your code to following:

```js
@ApiProperty({
  type: Number,
  default: new Date().now() // or something else...
})
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a separate annotation called `UpdateDateColumn` for storing updated date times.

```
  @IsOptional({ groups: [CREATE, UPDATE] })
  @UpdateDateColumn({ nullable: true })
  updateTime: Date;
```

The import statement is as follows -

```
import { PrimaryGeneratedColumn, CreateDateColumn, UpdateDateColumn, DeleteDateColumn, Column } from 'typeorm';
```